# How to implement an Update Profile page in PHP

Tags: php, sql, session, mysqli, session-variables

My question is exactly as the Title says: How would one go about creating and "update profile" page on a website?

Currently, I store the user's userid, username, and email after a successful login in SESSION variables. The problem is that when the user updates their profile by clicking a button, an external file named `process_updateprofile.php` is called. The `process_updateprofile.php` needs the SESSION stored userid in order to update that specific user's row in the Users table in my Database.

However, when I print out the SESSION userid variable, it returns NULL, and the SQL query doesn't execute because the `WHERE userid=?` statement in my prepared statement fails.

This is the code that starts the session at the top of my page:

```
        function sec_session_start() {
            $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
            $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
            $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
            session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
            session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
            session_start(); // Start the php session
            session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
        }
```

And this is the code that stores the userid in a SESSION variable when the user logs in:

```
$user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id); // XSS protection as we might print this value
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; 
$username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]+/", "", $username); // XSS protection as we might print this value
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Thanks!

Comment: So your question is not "how to implement an update profile page", but "why does the session value not carry over to my update profile page?" Are you starting the session on the profile update page? Is the session working on all other pages?

Comment: have you used session_start() method on each page which is using session like process_updateprofile.php ?